# sum up each individual values from 2 arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, sum, element

I'm trying to understand this conditional loop to sum up each elements from 2 arrays, but I stumble upon the latter part, I don't understand what is to be achieved there.

Can you please explain to me?

```
function Arrays_sum(array1, array2) {
    var result = [];
    var ctr = 0;
    var x = 0;

    if (array1.length === 0)
        return "array1 is empty";
    if (array2.length === 0)
        return "array2 is empty";

    while (ctr < array1.length && ctr < array2.length) {
        result.push(array1[ctr] + array2[ctr]);
        ctr++;
    }

    if (ctr === array1.length) //I don't understand from here onwards
    {
        for (x = ctr; x < array2.length; x++) {
            result.push(array2[x]);
        }
    } else {
        for (x = ctr; x < array1.length; i++) {
            result.push(array1[x]);
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: So the result of this function is either an array or string? o.0

Comment: Why do you have i++ on your 2nd for loop?

Comment: sorry2, typo, should be a "x", thanks all!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's suppose the following two arrays and their "sum":

```
Array 1: 1  2  3  4   5  6   7   8  9 [length = 9]
Array 2: 2  4  6  8   2  4   6        [length = 7]

Sum    : 3  6  9  12  7  10  13  8  9 [length = 9]
```

Pay attention to the last two items. The sum is equal to the value of the first array because the second array doesn't contain such number of values.

```
Array 1: 1  2  3  4   5  6   7   8  9
Array 2: 2  4  6  8   2  4   6   ?  ?
```

That's exactly what algorithm does:

1) While both arrays have numbers at `i` index - sum up.

```
ctr    : !  !  !  !   !  !   !  \|/   [ ctr   = 7 (remember: 0-based indexes)]       
Array 1: 1  2  3  4   5  6   7   8  9 [length = 9]
Array 2: 2  4  6  8   2  4   6        [length = 7]

Sum    : 3  6  9  12  7  10  13
```

Here `while (ctr < array1.length && ctr < array2.length)` conditions breaks at `ctr < array2.length`.

Further, the check `ctr == array2.length` returns true meaning that the Array 2 is over and we need to continue iterating through the `array1`.

```
for (x = ctr; x < array1.length; i++) {
    result.push(array1[x]);
}
```

2) While the remaining array is not over - add values from it.

```
x    :                           !  !  \|/ [  x    = 10]                     
Array 1: 1  2  3  4   5  6   7   8  9      [length = 9 ]
Array 2: 2  4  6  8   2  4   6             [length = 7 ]

Sum    : 3  6  9  12  7  10  13  8  9
```

Answer (score 1):

At the end of the first loop, the following assertion holds:

```
ctr === array1.length || ctr === array2.length
```

Observe the following scenario illustration:

```
array1: xxxxxxx    (length = 7)
array2: xxxxxxxxxx (length = 10)
               ^
               7 (ctr)
```

If the end of one array has been reached, it will continue to append each element of the other array from that point onwards. Of course, this assumes that elements outside of each array's bounds are considered to be `0`.

Technically, the function could have less edge cases by considering:

```
array2 is empty => yield array1
array1 is empty => yield array2
```

That said, because we're dealing with JavaScript we can bend the CS rules a little bit:

```
function array_sum(a, b)
{
  // iterate over the biggest array and map each value
  return (a.length > b.length ? a : b).map(function(value, index) {
    // to the sum of both, whereby 0 is assumed for non-existent elements
    return value + (b[index] || 0);
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As You can see hear you are using if because in while loop you are checking two array using && condition.

so if suppose **array1.length = 1** and  **array2.length = 2** and your **ctr = 1** then your **while loop** will be **stop** , but array2 has one more value remaining so for remaining Value they use **IF Condition**

```
if (ctr === array1.length) //I don't understand from here onwards
    {
        for (x = ctr; x < array2.length; x++) {
            result.push(array2[x]);
        }
    } else {
        for (x = ctr; x < array1.length; i++) {
            result.push(array1[x]);
        }
    }
```